# SQL count changes in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to count the changes in assigned group on a ticket. The problem is my log also count changes in assignee that are in the same group.

Here is some sample data

```
 ticket_id | assigned_group  | assignee   | date
----------------------------------------------------
 1001      | group A         | john       | 1-1-15
 1001      | group A         | michael    | 1-2-15
 1001      | group A         | jacob      | 1-3-15
 1001      | group B         | eddie      | 1-4-15
 1002      | group A         | john       | 1-1-15
 1002      | group B         | eddie      | 1-2-15
 1002      | group A         | john       | 1-3-15
 1002      | group B         | eddie      | 1-4-15
 1002      | group A         | john       | 1-5-15
```

I need this to return

```
ticket_id | count 
--------------------
10001     | 2
10002     | 4
```

My query is like this

```
select ticket_id, assigned_group, count(*) from mytable group by ticket_id, assigned_group
```

But that gives me

```
ticket_id | count 
--------------------
10001     | 4
10002     | 5
```

**edit:**

Also if I use

```
select ticket_id, count(Distinct assigned_group) as [Count] from mytable group by ticket_id
```

I only get

```
ticket_id | count 
--------------------
10001     | 2
10002     | 2
```

Any advice?

Comment: how do you count a ticket that change from group A to group B to group A to group B? would it be 2 or 3?

Comment: @Jayvee That would be 3. Each change counts even if its gone to that group before.

Comment: shouldn't the ticket 10001 have count 1

Comment: @Hoopdady what version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Distinct Count` to get the result

```
select ticket_id, count(Distinct assigned_group) as [Count] 
from mytable 
group by ticket_id
```

Comment: This won't work because if I add another entry for 1002 reassigning it to group B, it will still only be 2.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
with temp as
(
select ticket_id, assigned_group, count(*) as count,date from mytable group by ticket_id, assigned_group,date
)

select ticket_id, count from temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_number() function to look into the next record's value.

```
with tbl as (select *, row_number() over(partition by ticket_id order by 1) from table)

select a.ticket_id, a.assigned_group, a.assignee_name, a.date,
count(case when a.assigned_group <> b.assigned_group then 1 else 0 end) as No_of_change
from tbl as a
left join tbl as b
on a.rn = b.rn + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can use the LAG function to determine the previous assigned group easily. Then, if the previous assigned group is different from the current assigned group, you can increment the count, as below:

```
WITH previous_groups AS
(
  SELECT
    ticket_id,
    assign_date,
    assigned_group,
    LAG(assigned_group, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY assign_date) AS prev_assign_group
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT
    ticket_id,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN assigned_group <> prev_assign_group THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS count
FROM previous_groups
WHERE prev_assign_group IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY ticket_id;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or earlier versions, then you need an extra step to determine the previous assigned group, as below:

```
WITH previous_assign_dates AS
(
  SELECT
    mt1.ticket_id,
    mt1.assign_date,
    MAX(mt2.assign_date) AS prev_assign_date
  FROM mytable mt1
  LEFT JOIN mytable mt2
  ON mt1.ticket_id = mt2.ticket_id
  AND mt2.assign_date < mt1.assign_date
  GROUP BY
    mt1.ticket_id,
    mt1.assign_date
),
previous_groups AS
(
    SELECT
        mt1.*,
        mt2.assigned_group AS prev_assign_group
    FROM mytable mt1
    INNER JOIN previous_assign_dates pad
    ON mt1.ticket_id = pad.ticket_id
    AND mt1.assign_date = pad.assign_date
    LEFT JOIN mytable mt2
    ON pad.ticket_id = mt2.ticket_id
    AND pad.prev_assign_date = mt2.assign_date
)
SELECT
    ticket_id,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN assigned_group <> prev_assign_group THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS count
FROM previous_groups
WHERE prev_assign_group IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY ticket_id;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65b7c/4)</kbd>

**References**:
[The LAG function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ordinal number within the ticket, then a self join where the group is different and consecutive ordinals, should work:

```
SELECT t1.ticket_id, COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY date) ordinal 
FROM mytable) t1 
JOIN 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY date) ordinal FROM nytable) t2
ON t1.ticket_id=t2.ticket_id AND t1.assigned_group<>t2.assigned_group AND t1.ordinal+1=t2.ordinal
GROUP BY t1.ticket_id
```